# How to mask the numpy 2D array properly by the index condition?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array.

```
x = np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5)
```

I need to create a mask by index condition. For example elements with even indexes.

```
mask = np.zeros((5, 5), dtype=bool)

for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        if i % 2 == 0 and j % 2 == 0:
            mask[i][j] = True
```

Is there a way to create such a mask using numpy tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your nested loops with this:

```
mask[::2,::2] = True
```

The `::2` means "from beginning to end, for every second element" in each axis.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: @not_alex: You're welcome, and welcome to Stack Overflow.  If this answer solved your problem you can "accept" it by clicking the checkmark on the left.